# Optimising AJAX calls

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm quite new to AJAX (jQuery AJAX to be specific) and I want to post to a PHP function (through WordPress) 3 times. Instead of sending 3 POST requests, is there a way to just call merge the AJAX call?

Currently I have the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: ajaxurl,
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    data: { action: 'box', id: box_id, target: "float", value_aj: "none" }
});

$.ajax({
    url: ajaxurl,
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    data: { action: 'box', id: box_id, target: "width", value_aj: "1499" }
});

$.ajax({
    url: ajaxurl,
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    data: { action: 'box', id: box_id, target: "margin", value_aj: "auto"}
});
```

Surely there's a better way to do this? Basically the function that's receiving the data is just posting to a text file.

Sometimes without async it will only run the 3rd AJAX call too? So I put on async but obviously that will block until the 3 are done (which is bad).

Is there a more optimal way to do this within just one call?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have control over the receiving script you might modify it to accept not a single, but an array of actions instead. And send one request with an array of 3 actions as its body.

Comment: Lesson #1...never use `async:false`. It blocks other script from running and can cause you lots of headaches as well as user frustration

Comment: Or send the requests async. Using `async:false` is not good.

Comment: Hi @JimCote when I send them async it tends to forget the first 3 requests, which is strange.

Comment: @charlietfl is there solution via jQuery? If not I guess I'll just modify the PHP script.

Comment: Not fully understanding the issue to be honest. How is `box_id` defined? If it's part of a loop that couldd be a problem

Comment: You can restructure your ajax call (both client and server) to send an array of data rather than just a single object, thus you can send 1 or more objects at once rather than having to make separate ajax calls for each object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is just the same as OP do, but async. And with use of ajaxSetup

```
$.ajaxSetup(
    {
        url: ajaxurl, 
        cache: false 
    }
);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: { action: 'box', id: box_id, target: "float", value_aj: "none" }
    success: function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: { action: 'box', id: box_id, target: "width", value_aj: "1499" }
            success: function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { action: 'box', id: box_id, target: "margin", value_aj: "auto"}
                });
            }
    });
    }
});
```

Comment: 1. `POST` requests cannot be cached 2. It's really a controversial use of `$.ajaxSetup` to save one line of code.

Comment: @zerkms is t okay to use say just the bottom piece of code, on success of each call, do the following? Does it block anything using this method?

Comment: @user3724954 not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: @zerkms currently I'm doing 3 ajax calls one after another and sometimes one of the calls don't work, using a 'success:' on the call, would it block anything by using success -> do ajax again - if that makes sense? The code above (without the cache and ajaxSetup) sees to work fine, but I worry it may just be similar to async: false?

Comment: @user3724954 it isn't similar to async:false. It will do each next ajax call only on success of previous.

Comment: @aleha great, so it's the most optimal way to do it then I presume? Because before only the last AJAX call was working.

Comment: @user3724954 yes it is normal to do next ajax call from success or done callback.